# Open split Access database in Excel VBA with file path based on the user

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open a split Access database in Excel VBA using wildcards in place of my name in the file path.

I am on an office network. My path is `C:\User\francisco.dias\Documents\Data\Data.accde`. I want to set a path in the VBA code so that different users can access the database from their computer (e.g. `C:\User\*\Documents\Data\Data.accde`).

I've tried:

```vb
fPath = Dir("C:\User\francisco.dias\documents\Datalink\Data.accde")
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fPath, ReadOnly:=False)
```

Comment: You should use `Environment` to obtain the specific path for each user. What you try is not possible. You can use wildcard  only in the last path element. File name or folder  name... But in your case it is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not a VBA programmer, just trying my best to get this work. Could you please help me to write some code for that. I think I can get it through TextBox/Variable, but is there a way to get it without user input?.

Comment: OK. I will post an answer to solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the next way(s):

```
   Dim myDocsPath As String, fPath  As String
   myDocsPath = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\My Documents"
   fPath = myDocsPath & "\Datalink\Data.accde"
   
   Debug.Print fPath 'you can see the returned path in Immediate Window (Ctrl + G, being in VBE)
```

But the above solution will work only if programs like `OneDrive` have not been installed on computer.

So, a more reliable solution would be to use a VBScript object:

```
  Dim objFolders As Object, myDocsPath As String, fPath  As String
  Set objFolders = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders

  myDocsPath = objFolders("mydocuments")
  fPath = myDocsPath & "\Datalink\Data.accde"
  Debug.Print fPath
```

It will return correctly in any environment...

Comment: Is also the case that `Data.accde` is an Access database and you're opening an Excel workbook so it will open and ask which tables/queries you wish to import to Excel.  Just double-checking that's definitely what's required.....

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook I don't open anything... I only adapted his code to correctly return the path independent of user name, as required. I observed the strange extension but I thought it maybe is a typo. But I think it would be better to delete the lines where he tries opening (something), referring only to the necessary path. Thanks!

Comment: My apologise, Darren has pointed out right. I need to open a access Database file in excel, I am storing my data on access database.. And that access file has been splited for backend and frontend use. The file extension mention above is correct and not a typo. Will this code work or needs to be change ?.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @FaneDuru.  I should've put the comment on the original post.  Fran - the code will work for returning the documents folder.  If you try and open the database in Excel it will open an import form so you can select the tables to import.  I'm guessing you'd want specific table/queries to be imported though.

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru. Your codes did worked. I used WScript code. Thank you once again.